# Unable to get current location button on map

Tags: java, android

Unable to access current location of user.. 
...
.
.

```
package com.example.admin.myapplication;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 21-Nov-16.
 */
public class Map extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {


    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (googleServicesAvailable()) {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.map);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            initMap();
        } else {
            //No Google Maps Layout
        }
    }

    private void initMap() {
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_type_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean googleServicesAvailable() {
        GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int isAvailable = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else if (api.isUserResolvableError(isAvailable)) {
            Dialog dialog = api.getErrorDialog(this, isAvailable, 0);
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to play services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        goToLocationZoom(31.773214,76.984563,16);


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }

    private void goToLocationZoom(double lat, double lng, float zoom) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate upadatezoom = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(upadatezoom);
    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more detail? Unclear what exactly you're trying to do / what fails.

Comment: @Paresh  The answer in the linked duplicate will solve your issue.  It looks like the main thing you are missing is code to prompt the user to accept the Location permission at runtime.